# Pycharm Run Window pdb: Can not correct/modify typed code

Tags: python, pycharm, pdb

Having Problem in Pycharm run window.

My goal is to type:

[image]

But by mistake I have typed:

[image]

When I step the cursor inside `query()` and start typing:
[image]

after typing the first letter cursor jumps to the end of the line.

Is it a bug or feature? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug [IDEA-171432](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171432) and I don't think there's a workaround, unfortunately. Please vote for the ticket.